# Streaming live video broadcast from android camera to server

Tags: android, video, android-camera, live-streaming

I am trying to create an android application in which i want to broadcast live video from the android device camera to server so that all user can access live video from the server . What is the best approach to achieve this ?

I don't know the right way. If any way with live video streaming from the device camera to help me out....??

Comment: @[Wit3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2121070/wit3) posted a link to [Android Streaming live camera video to web page](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/) tutorial. It is actually a good link, even though using links as answers is strongly discouraged on SO. The bottom line is to use [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) if you care about the latency and not the video quality. Its an open-source project that provides web browsers and mobile applications with real-time communication. It allows audio and video with direct peer-to-peer communication.

We have also implemented Video Calling using webRTC and it works like a charm.